# Create a new release after changing a branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I made a mistake when I created a new Release (tag) in GitHub:

1. Merge everything into "master"
2. Create a release 1.1.0 but on branch "develop" -> mistake should be "master"
3. Working on a "hotfix-1.1.1" branch
4. Merge "hotfix-1.1.1" into "master"
5. Create a release 1.1.1 on "master"
6. Realized that release 1.1.0 was wrong and deleted it

Is it still possible to create a Release on the code base of version 1.1.0 or is it too late? If yes how?

Comment: Which CI/CD tool you are using ? where is the release code stored (like nexus for java, npm for node) ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can apply tag to historical commits. You can delete a tag and reassign tag to another commit.

[More Info on Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

1. First checkout master branch

   `git checkout master`
2. Get the commit of the master branch for which you want to apply the tag 1.1.0

   `git log --pretty=oneline`
3. Once you get the commit, you want to tag 1.1.0, you can delete the tag 1.1.0, as it is pointing to develop branch commit

   `git tag -d 1.1.0`
4. Now apply tag 1.1.0 to the right commit(say SHA1), you got from Step No. 2

   `git tag -a 1.1.0 SHA1 -m "Release 1.1.0"`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
Simply using the hash of the commit corresponding to the 'last state of your deleted develop branch'.

If needed you may need to look to the commit history to find it back, for instance:

```
git log --patch
```

According to your integration/build system, you may need to create a new branch on this commit, from its hash:

```
git branch develop-resurrection <your commit hash>
```

If it is not enough to reach your needs; can you explain what is your integration/build system?